# $f'(t)+f(t) \leq g(t)$ implies $f(t) \leq g(t)$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ be $C^1$ functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

If $f'(t)+f(t) \leq g(t)$ holds with $f(0)=0 \leq g(t)$ for all $t$, can I conclude that $f(t) \leq g(t)$ for $t \geq 0$?

It seems qualitatively probable but I cannot prove rigorously...Could anyone help me?

Comment: You can get $f(t) \le e^{-t}f(0) + \int_0^t e^{-(t-s)} g(s) ds$.

Comment: How?? And what about $f(t) \leq g(t)$?

Comment: Multiply both sides of your inequality by $e^t$ and integrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f'+f=g$ with $f(0) = 0$ then
$f(t) = \int_0^t e^{-(t-s)} g(s) ds$.

Suppose we start with $g(s)=1$, then eventually $f(t) \to 1$, so then smoothly
reduce $g$ to zero and we will have $f(t) >0$ subsequently.

For an explicit example, take $g(t) = e^{-2t}$, then
$f(t) = e^{-t}-e^{-2t}$. Then $f(t)>g(t)$ for $t > 2$.

Comment: Oops, I did not mean to usurp Hagen's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $f(t_1)>g(t_1)$ for some $t_1>0$. Let $t_0=\sup\{\,t\mid t<t_1, f(t)\le g(t)\,\}$. Then $0\le t_0<t_1$ and $f(t_0)=g(t_0)$. For some $\tau\in(t_0,t_1)$, we have $f'(\tau)=\frac{f(t_1)-f(t_0)}{t_1-t_0}>0$ and hence $f'(\tau)+f(\tau)>f(\tau)> g(\tau)$, contradiction.

This method does not work for $t<0$, though.
In fact, it can't: with $f(t):=e^{-t}-1$ and $g(t)=1$, we have $f(t)+f'(t)=-1\le g(t)$ for all $t$, but $f(-1)=e-1>1$.

Comment: I did not assume that $g$ is increasing. I think my conclusion was wrong according to the answer below.

Comment: Why is $f(t_1)-f(t_0)>0$?

Comment: Answer is not correct since it assumes $g$ is monotone and that is not part of the original assumptions